# Camunda - Intermedia message event cannot correlate to a single execution

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I created a small application (Spring Boot and camunda) to process an order process. The Order-Service receives the new order via Rest and calls the Start Event of the BPMN Order workflow. The order process contains two asynchronous JMS calls (Customer check and Warehouse Stock check). If both checks return the order process should continue.

The Start event is called within a Spring Rest Controller:

```
     ProcessInstance processInstance =
             runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("orderService", String.valueOf(order.getId()));
```

The Send Task (e.g. the customer check) sends the JMS message into a asynchronous queue.
The answer of this service is catched by a another Spring component which then trys to send an intermediate message:

```
     runtimeService.createMessageCorrelation("msgReceiveCheckCustomerCredibility")
             .processInstanceBusinessKey(response.getOrder().getBpmnBusinessKey())
             .setVariable("resultOrderCheckCustomterCredibility", response)
             .correlate();
```

I deactivated the warehouse service to see if the order process waits for the arrival of the second call, but instead I get this exception:

```
  1115 06:33:08.564 WARN  [o.c.b.e.jobexecutor] ENGINE-14006 Exception while executing job  67d2cc24-0769-11ea-933a-d89ef3425300: 
  org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.MismatchingMessageCorrelationException: ENGINE-13031 Cannot correlate a message with name 'msgReceiveCheckCustomerCredibility' to a single execution. 4 executions match the correlation keys: CorrelationSet [businessKey=1, processInstanceId=null, processDefinitionId=null, correlationKeys=null, localCorrelationKeys=null, tenantId=null, isTenantIdSet=false]
```

This is my process. I cannot see a way to post my bpmn file :-(
[image]

What can't it not correlate with the message name and the business key? The JMS queues are empty, there are other messages with the same businessKey waiting.

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue (but a different scenario to you), but adding a unique business key when creating the process instance worked for me, e.g. ```runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey(...).businessKey(<unique key>).execute();```. Then when correlating the message, I used ```runtimeService.createMessageCorrelation(...).processInstanceBusinessKey(<unique key>).correlate();```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to narrow the problem: Do a runtimeService eventSubscription query before you try to correlate and check what subscriptions are actually waiting .. maybe you have a duplicate message name? Maybe you (accidentally) have another instance of the same process running?   Once you identified the subscriptions, you could just notify the execution directly without using the correlation builder ...

Comment: Hi. I checked the subscriber list of the two intermediate message "listener" and there are several subscribers of the same message (activityId) with the same business Key in each of them. So that explains a lot. You are right. They have different processInstanceId and different executionId. I think the last should be different, but why do they have different processInstanceIds? I have Spring Boot and restart it a lot. Do I have to start camunda with a given processInstanceId to "reconnect" to the previous processId?  Thank you!

Comment: During dev it is advisable to either use an inmemory dB or tweak the processes.xml with something like „undeploy on start“ (google this).  Otherwise processinstances from previous runs remain in th db

Comment: I miss-managed my active process instances. That was the problem. Thank you very much!